# Optimizing queries on related tables in Sequelize

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I would like to know if there is a better way to obtain the following result: filtering a list of rows with values from table that's connected through a many-to-many relationship.
In my example case, it's songs that feature certain instruments.

Here is my songs model:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var Song = sequelize.define('songs', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10).UNSIGNED,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        title: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
            allowNull: false
        },
    }, {
        tableName: 'songs',
        timestamps: false
    });

    Song.associate = function (models) {
        Song.belongsToMany(models.instruments, {through: 'songs_instruments', foreignKey: 'song_id'})
    };

    return Song
};
```

Here is my instruments model:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var Instrument = sequelize.define('instruments', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10).UNSIGNED,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
            allowNull: false
        }
    }, {
        tableName: 'instruments',
        timestamps: false,
    });

    Instrument.associate = function (models) {
        Instrument.belongsToMany(models.songs, {through: 'songs_instruments', foreignKey: 'instrument_id'})
    };

    return Instrument
};
```

Here is the model for the join table:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    return sequelize.define('songs_instruments', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10).UNSIGNED,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        song_id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10).UNSIGNED,
            allowNull: false,
            references: {
                model: 'songs',
                key: 'id'
            }
        },
        instrument_id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10).UNSIGNED,
            allowNull: false,
            references: {
                model: 'instruments',
                key: 'id'
            }
        }
    }, {
        tableName: 'songs_instruments',
        timestamps: false
    });
};
```

And here is the way I am currently doing my fetching (`args['instruments']` contains a list of the instruments I want to filter the songs for):

```
const instruments = await db.instruments.findAll({
    where: {name: args['instruments']}
})

const songs_instruments = await db.songs_instruments.findAll({
    where: {instrument_id: instruments.map(instrument => instrument.id)}
})

const songs = await db.songs.findAll({
    where: {id: songs_instruments.map(song => song.song_id)}
})
return songs
```

While this works correctly, and in the end I get the results that I expect, I can't help but wonder if there is a more efficient way of querying the database, as doing it like this causes a total of three queries to be executed:

```
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `name` FROM `instruments` AS `instruments` WHERE `instruments`.`name` IN ('Vocals', 'Trumpet', 'Guitar');
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `song_id`, `instrument_id` FROM `songs_instruments` AS `songs_instruments` WHERE `songs_instruments`.`instrument_id` IN (1, 3, 7);
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `title` FROM `songs` AS `songs` WHERE `songs`.`id` IN (1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3);
```

I am quite new to Sequelize, hence my probably incorrect/suboptimal way of achieving my goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh i totally missed that.. it was late.. yes you can do that.. add the as like below to alias this connection, and do the same in songs with as: 'instruments'... you don't need to fetch the join records..

```
Instrument.associate = function (models) {
        Instrument.belongsToMany(models.songs, {through: 'songs_instruments', as: 'songs', foreignKey: 'instrument_id', otherKey: 'song_id'})
    };

const instruments = await db.instruments.findAll({
    where: {name: args['instruments']},
    {
     include: [{
        model: db.songs,
        as: 'songs', 
        through: db.songs_instruments,
      }]
   }
});
```

OR Something along the lines of the include below...

```
const songs = await db.songs.findAll({
          include: [{
            model: db.instruments,
            as: 'instruments', 
            through: db.songs_instruments,
            where: {name: args['instruments']}
          }],
        });
```

Comment: Can you put that instrument model code in again as it is now so I can look at it?

Comment: I have tried adding the `as` in the `belongsToMany` function, and then doing the call as you suggested (`const songs = await instruments.getSongs();`) and what I get is `instruments.getSongs is not a function`.
I figured out I have to do `const songs = await instruments[0].getSongs();`: this works, but I don't like fetching a list and then throwing it away.
Is there any better way of doing it (besides just calling `db.instruments.findOne`)?

Comment: I cannot put the whole model in the comment, however it looks just like before but with the addition of the `as` parameter, so the content of the `associate` function now is `Instrument.belongsToMany(models.songs, {as: 'songs', through: 'songs_instruments', foreignKey: 'instrument_id'})`.

Comment: i just meant update your code above so that we can see where we are... change your original code to what it is now in those snippets

Comment: I have found out that adding the `as` or not in the `belongsToMany` function doesn't make any difference: in both cases, this works
`const instruments = await db.instruments.findAll({
    where: {name: args['instruments']}
})
const songs = await instruments[0].getSongs();`
and this doesn't
`const instruments = await db.instruments.findAll({
    where: {name: args['instruments']}
})
const songs = await instruments.getSongs();`
So, the problem is that `getSongs` is a method of the single instrument instance, and not of the whole array returned by `findAll`.

Comment: The include is probably the better way for you to go anyway... as it will nest your data..... but if you don't care about any of the data from the instruments list, and don't want nested data then you can use the include logic i posted above but add a where into it... however you'll want to do it from the other way... you'll want to call find all on songs and include instruments and add a where under the through clause... that where would be what you are currently passing into your instrument findAll... i will edit the above for that

Comment: i edited the code above using the include... i am not in front of my code at the moment but i think that is close to proper syntax, and this is well documented, if i read correctly, you simply want the songs for the instruments you passed in, so you don't want to bother fetching all instruments and then the related songs and throwing away the original fetch... if so the include is way closer to what you want

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using dataloader, and your three queries are batched.. i think you are all good... You are clearly taking advantage of the model setups with sequelize so it's got to be versatile, i don't see a problem here

Comment: I think there should be some way doing that all in one query... something like this:
`SELECT * FROM songs s JOIN songs_instruments si ON (s.id = si.song_id) JOIN instruments i ON (i.id = si.instrument_id) WHERE i.name IN ('Keyboard', 'Trumpet');`
I am aware of methods such as `getParents` that become available when a `belongsToMany` relationship is implemented, so I was wondering if I could somehow use those.
Because right now, I am not getting any benefit from setting up the relationship in Sequelize: I am just querying one table at a time, without any join.